# Select Polymer element by dynamic attribute value

Tags: javascript, polymer

Consider this element:

```
<file-list type="Person" oid="[[person.id]]"></file-list>
```

I have several of them on my Polymer SPA with various values for the attributes `type` and `person`.

Selecting them like this, works:

```
var f = document.querySelectorAll("file-list[type='Person']");
```

but like that, not:

```
var f = document.querySelectorAll("file-list[oid='" + oid + "']");
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The element is set up like this:

```
Polymer({
    is : "file-list",
    properties : {
        oid : {
            type : String
        },
        type : {
            type : String
        }
    }
    // ... etc
});
```

Comment: what will `oid ` be evaluated to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use attribute binding to be able to use it as selector

```
<file-list type="Person" oid$="[[person.id]]"
```

this way the attribute will be added to the DOM, otherwise it will only assigned to a property which are not considered for selectors.